# Resume - stuck on experience

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, resume

I want to prepare a resume , I finished M.Sc. in 2012, and have 7 months as internship experience in java from June 2013 toDecember 2013,

And From January 2014 to till now I am working as a .net developer. This is my first job related to my graduation .Where ever I attended an interview, the first question that arises was what I did from 2012 and why.

I have only 3 months of experience in .net now, this company is not a good fit for me at all .That's why I want to switch to another opportunity in a bigger, possibly multinational company.

I am unclear as to how to mention my experience in my resume . I dont want to appear as a fresher with nothing except 3 months of experience .On the other hand I don't deem the internship in Java as relevant experience.

What can I do to make this look better?

Comment: @CMW NO. There should be verify by third party checking

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not

Comment: @BAP It is being checked by others. That's what the comment is for. I invite you to point out the difference to your question.

Comment: Hey BAP, and welcome to [workplace.se]! It looks like you [asked the same question twice](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/22413/). The other was put [on hold](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions), so rather than deleting it and asking the same question, you should edit that question and it will automatically be put in the reopen queue for community review. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Did you experience the world of work during your internship?  Yes?  Well, that's valid work experience then!

It doesn't matter if it was paid or unpaid, part time or full, junior or high level - you did the work, you got the experience, you get to put it on your CV.

Comment: Also, skills in the specific language are only a small part of the experience you gain in a position.  Most things transcend language: design, testing, *actually shipping product on time*, collaboration, dealing with ever-changing requirements...